Displaying MangoDB data on the Streamlit Webpage
I’m currently developing a web application for a recommendation system that operates locally and retrieves data from MongoDB. The application workflow begins with a student logging in using their unique student ID and password. Upon successful verification of these credentials, the system should grant access to the student, displaying personalized recommendations fetched from the MongoDB database associated with their student ID. However, despite successful login attempts, the system consistently returns a message indicating that no student ID is available, preventing the display of recommendations.
client = MongoClient(uri, server_api=ServerApi('1'))

# Send a ping to confirm a successful connection
try:
    client.admin.command('ping')
    print("Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

# Connect to MongoDB
db = client['GradProjDB']
collection = db['Students']  # Assuming 'Students' is the collection name
job_recommendations_collection = db['Job Recommendations per Student']  # Assuming 'JobRecommendations' is the collection name
course_recommendations_collection = db['Course Recommendations per Student']


def login_page(number1, number2):
    st.title("Login")
    student_id = st.text_input("Student ID", key=f"student_id_{number1}")
    password = st.text_input("Password", type="password", key=f"password_{number2}")
    if st.button("Login"):
       # print("Attempting login with Student ID:", student_id)
      #  print("Password:", password)
        # Check credentials against MongoDB
        student = collection.find_one({"Student_ID": student_id, "Password": str(password).strip()})
        #print("Result from MongoDB query:", student)
        if student:
            st.success("Login successful!")
            print("Login successful!")
            return True, student_id
        
        else:
            st.error("Incorrect student ID or password. Please try again.")
            print("Incorrect student ID or password. Please try again.")
            return False, None

def recommendations_page(student_id):
st.title(“Recommendations”)
# Ensure student_id is a string
student_id = str(student_id)
print(“Searching recommendations for student ID:”, student_id)

# Query the job recommendations collection for the specified student_id
recommendations_cursor = job_recommendations_collection.find({"Student_ID": student_id})
recommendations_count = 0

# Count the number of recommendations for the student
for _ in recommendations_cursor:
    recommendations_count += 1

if recommendations_count > 0:
    print("Recommendations found for student ID:", student_id)
    # Reset cursor to the beginning
    recommendations_cursor.rewind()
    
    # Iterate over the cursor to find the matching document
    for document in recommendations_cursor:
        if document["Student_ID"] == student_id:
            recommended_job_title = document.get("Recommended_Job_Title", "No recommendation found")
            company = document.get("Company", "")
            location = document.get("Location", "")
            job_link = document.get("Job_Link", "")
            similarity_score = document.get("Similarity_Score", "")
            
            st.write(f"Recommended Job Title: {recommended_job_title}")
            st.write(f"Company: {company}")
            st.write(f"Location: {location}")
            st.write(f"Job Link: {job_link}")
            st.write(f"Similarity Score: {similarity_score}")
            break
else:
    print("No recommendation found for student ID:", student_id)
    st.error("No recommendations found for this Student ID.")


sidebar_option = "Login"  # Default to login page
number1, number2 = 1, 2
login_result = login_page(number1, number2)
if login_result is not None:  # Check if login is successful
    logged_in, student_id = login_result
    sidebar_option = st.sidebar.radio("Navigation", ["Recommendations", "Grade Prediction", "Dashboard Analysis"])

    # Display selected page
    if sidebar_option == "Recommendations":
        recommendations_page(student_id)
    elif sidebar_option == "Grade Prediction":
        predictions_page()
    elif sidebar_option == "Dashboard Analysis":
        dashboard_page()

Please help!!!!
I tried multiple ways but nothing is working.
